# inserting text into SQL from a drop down list in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Help is very much needed and appreciated. I am working on a project that requires me to select a value from a drop down menu, and insert it into my database. The drop down list is loaded through a stored proc and data binding, and works well. But when I press the button to insert the data, it will ONLY insert the default text -- Select Chemical -- , or if that is not there, it will insert whatever is in the first selection. It never sees the other items.

My CONTENT Code:

```
<table width="95%" style="padding-left:200px; padding-top:50px">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:large; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:50px">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ChemLot" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td colspan="2" align="center" >
            <asp:Label ID="lblchemMessage" runat="server" Visible="false" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center" >
        <br />
        <br />
             <asp:Button ID="AddChemLots" OnClick= "AddChemLot2" Text="Add New Chemical Lot" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="250px" BackColor="Azure" />
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

The Code BEHIND:

```
protected void AddChemLot2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        String chemical = ChemLot.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
        SqlConnection m_sqlConnection;
        string m_connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ChemicalConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (m_sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(m_connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_Chem"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = m_sqlConnection;
                m_sqlConnection.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChemName", chemical);
            }

            int check = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            m_sqlConnection.Close();
```

My Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadList();
    }    
}

public void LoadList()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ChemicalConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Load_Chem"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                ChemLot.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                ChemLot.DataTextField = "Chemical";
                ChemLot.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You don't have an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here. This isn't complete. Probably you're lacking your Page_Load method as part of the question. We can certainly guess why `ChemLot.SelectedItem.Text` isn't what you expect it to be,  but you really need to learn what an MCVE is and include the relevant code yourself. Might as well make it minimal too - we don't need to see all the `<tr><td><br />` stuff in your question

Comment: You are probably doing the databind on postbacks, which is throwing away your selected value. Also, if you are just starting out, don't use table-based designs, or web forms.  Skip straight to MVC, you won't regret it.  Also, the dataAdapter isn't needed here at all, just use the SqlCommand.

Comment: Did you see how I formatted your code according to standard C# conventions and removed all the extra whitespace? Please do that any time you are posting code to Stack Overflow. Readability in your question is important.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SelectedItem.Value` or `SelectedValue` instead like

```
String chemical = ChemLot.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
```

Additional: There is no point in checking the below condition inside event handler since it will always be `true`

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
```

As I see from your current edit: you have below. You haven't specified the `DataValueField` at all anywhere.

```
ChemLot.DataTextField = "Chemical";
ChemLot.DataBind();
```

You should specify both

```
ChemLot.DataTextField = "Chemical";
ChemLot.DataValueField = <something>;
ChemLot.DataBind();
```

Comment: This probably isn't going to be the full answer - he's probably resetting the selected value on postback.

Comment: When I use the SelectedItem.Value, it gives me 0, instead of the text.

Comment: @M.Beamon, that's great ... post your code for filling the dropdown and what you are doing at `page_load`

Comment: @mason, couldn't disagree ... most likely

Comment: I don't know how to edit the post so I can add my page load

Comment: It won't always be true that you're in a postback in a button click handler. Someone could easily call `AddChemLot2(this, null);` directly. But yeah, the check there is pretty much useless.

Comment: @mason, what purpose would it satisfy calling an event handler?

Comment: @Rahul None in most cases. But my point is that your statement `There is no point in checking the below condition inside event handler since it will always be true` is not correct. There exists a condition where you could be within that method and it may not be a postback. The check doesn't make sense there either way.

Comment: I see the edit, and added the DataValueField = "Chemical";

Comment: It has not changed anything.

Comment: @M.Beamon, post the query in `Load_Chem` procedure

Comment: @M.Beamon Then you probably have not created a proper [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's up to you to find the complete amount of code that fully demonstrates your issue. The ability to figure formulate a proper MCVE is a very important skill for a programmer.

Comment: @ Rahul, thank you for trying to help. I will post that now

Comment: @Rahul...The Load_Chem stored proc is a simple query of the data base, there is nothing special to it. How would I be resetting the drop down list in the page load if I have the   if (!this.IsPostBack), how can I prevent that. I feel that is the issue.